# If $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$ then $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ OR $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}g(x)=0$

Tags: limits

I'm struggling to decide whether it is true or not: (part of HW)

Let $\mathbb\\f, g$ be two functions defined on [$\mathbb\\a, \infty$) for some $\mathbb\\a \in R$ such that
$\mathbb\\f(x) \ge 0$ and $\mathbb\\g(x) > 0$ for every $\mathbb\\x \ge a$:

If $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$ then $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ OR $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}g(x)=0$.

i.e. - is it true that one of the two must exist?

Comment: Aren't you going against your working assumption that $g(x) > 0$?

Comment: No, if g(x)=1/x, then clearly for [1,infinity) - g(x)>0 and its limit is 0.

Comment: You can say that either $\liminf g(x)=0$ or $\lim f(x) =+\infty$

Comment: But how can you prove such thing?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If $g(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ and $f(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}x$, then $f(x)/g(x)\to \infty$ but $\liminf g(x)=-1$  and $\lim f(x)$ is not $+\infty$. I see, there are more assumptions in the body of the question.

Comment: Sure, but $g(x)>0$ is an assumption in the question. @MoonLightSyzygy  if that condition is removed, then you have to put absolute values in my statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true! (Note that there is no continuity assumption on $f$ and $g$). Let $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=\frac  1 x$ on the intervals $[2na,2(n+1)a)$ and $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1 $ on the intervals $[2(n+1)a,2(n+2)a)$. Then $\frac  {f(x)} {g{(x)}}=x \to \infty$ but the conclusion fails.

Comment: Would the similar result hold if functions were restricted to continuous ones?

Comment: Yes, it is surely possible to make the functions continuous using piece-wise linear functions, but the writing is  a little more involved. @tstanisl

Comment: @tstanisl, for $x\gt0$, let $g(x)=1-(1-e^{-x})\cos x$ and $f(x)=xg(x)$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Good example.

Comment: I've set f(x) to be 1 in [0,1) and x in [1, infinity), but how can you prove that its limit is not infinity? Because it seems like its limit is infinity

Comment: @AviAsks I am taking a sequnce of intervals moving off to $\infty$ and defining $f$ to be alternately $1$ and $x$ in those intervals. ($n$ is varying in the defnition). So $f(x)$ does not tend to $\infty$.